# Float text over bottom positioned box

Tags: css, css-float

I'd like to code html+css to achieve result as shown on attached image: [image].

I mean the coding part with text and arrow box. Putting just position absolute is not an answer, cause I need text to float round the arrow box. Is there any way to do that?

I've alredy tried putting all kinds of floats on box and paragraf tag with text. Placing arrow box before, after and in paragraf tag. Also tried using vertical-align and position on arrow box.

Fiddle to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/K2S5y/1/

```
<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas males elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula.</p>
<div class="arrowMore">arr</div>                
</div>

.content{width:170px;height:170px;border:1px solid red;}
.arrowMore{background:blue;width:70px;height:70px;}
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific

Answer (score 1):

Use clear:both ex.

```
<div style="float:left; width:300px">
    <img/>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:300px">
    Text text text
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

you can see the live example here:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl-css-float-examples.htm#floating

Answer (score 0):

```css
#arrow {
  float: right;
}

/* then possibly  */
#arrow:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It seems that pure html/css do not offer a solution to stick it to the bottom right while it still pushes the text out of the way. Top right is easy but I have no clue why it isn't possible to align to the bottom. It seems like such a simple thing to do. :/